# True or false: The contrapositive statement of "$\text{not } A\implies \text{not } B$" is "$A\implies B$"?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> **Question** : State whether 'True' or 'False' and justify your answer giving reason.
>
> The contrapositive statement of "$\text{not } A\implies \text{not } B$" is "$A\implies B$" where $A$ and $B$ are two statements.

I know that when $A\implies B$ is equivalent to it's Contrapositive namely "$\text{not } B\implies \text{not } A$" that is if $B$ doesn't hold then $A$ doesn't hold.

I asked this question because I have never been taught this by my teacher and text given in my book is just given in 3 - 4 lines which is totally insufficient. Kindly help at least a bit.
Even if know that the answer is true but I don't know how to justify it.

I tried to take this example :

$ x\neq -2 \implies x^2\neq4$ is equivalent to it's Contrapositive $x = -2\implies x^2 = 4$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the contrapositive of 
$$\neg A\longrightarrow \neg B$$
is $$\neg(\neg B)\longrightarrow \neg(\neg A)$$
but I think we're allowed to know that $\neg \neg A \equiv A, \neg\neg B \equiv B$, hence
the contrapostive is
$$B\longrightarrow A$$
which is not the same as $A\longrightarrow B$. So the answer is false.

In general, the [law of contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) says that the $P\longrightarrow Q$ and its contrapositive 
$$\neg Q\longrightarrow \neg P$$
are logically equivalent.

---

Using the example given, the contrapostive of
$ x\neq -2 \implies x^2\neq4$ 
is 
$$x^2 = 4\implies x = -2.$$

Comment: Kindly see the example I have taken in my edited question details.

Comment: @user109256 I have updated my answer. Your contrapositive is incorrect.

Comment: so can I use your correct example to prove that the given statement is false.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. Yes, you can. Just make sure clearly state the claim using the example, and clearly state the correct contrapositive and say that they are not equivalent.

Comment: thank you for helping me understand this method of proofs to some extent. Actually I've got my exam tomorrow and I have completed my whole syllabus. Now I was working on some miscellaneous things and this one crept up. So I asked it here to get some help. By the way I'm doing maths major and in my first year. My prof. never taught us these types of logical things. Are they not a part of first semester syllabus or he forgot to teach us this. Will these topics be taught in detail in upcoming classes in the next semester?

Comment: That's hard to say. It sounds like you're taking a "discrete math" class, in which case he/she should have covered it, I think. Regardless, you will often find that even if the teacher "never taught" something, you are still responsible for the material if it was covered in the text book. I doubt this will be "covered" in the future. However, looking forward, you are expected to know this since it is often used in proofs.

Answer (score -2):

You can think like this :

The contrapositive of ' not A => not B ' is ' not( not A => not B ) ' which simplify to ' A not(=>) B ' which is ' A <- B '